# Appcelerator titanium transition between windows

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

May be a noob question about appcelerator titanium:
I have an index.xml page like this :

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container" layout="composite" backgroundImage="/images/login/background.png" id="wLogin">
    <!-- Here content-->
</Window>
```

and the controller to open page2 :

```
function openPage2() {
    var win = Alloy.createController('page2').getView().open();
   $.wLogin.close();
};
```

This works fine, but i want slide (left to right or right to left) each time i change page, i test on iphone simulator.

I think it should be a basic functionnality, or i'm wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To have the native transition you must add your Window into a `NavigationWindow` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

```
 <NavigationWindow id="nav">
  <Window class="container" layout="composite" backgroundImage="/images/login/background.png" id="wLogin">
      <!-- Here content-->
  </Window>
<NavigationWindow>
```

Then in your .js :

```
function openPage2() {
    var win = Alloy.createController('page2').getView();
    $.nav.openWindow(win, {animated:true});
};
```

Comment: Thank you for help but it not working, because i am in simulator? or i have to add navigaitonwindow to page2 also?

Comment: On the .js that contains the NavigationWindow, did you open the NavigationWindow instead the login window ? `$.nav.open()` That's the problem ? You havent a transition or the page2 window didnt show ?

Comment: the .js that contains the NavigationWindow is the index.js, i open the page2 window from it:

function openPage2() {
    var win = Alloy.createController('page2').getView();
    $.nav.openWindow(win, {animated:true});
};